# Wordpress Pagination archive/category

Tags: wp-query, categories, pagination, archives

I have a problem with creating a simple pagination for the categories with `WP_Query`.
I've got it to work for the archive, but if I try the same on the category template, then I get redirected to the landing page.

Here is my code for the archive when it is working.

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
        'paged'           => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,
);
  $archquery = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $archquery->have_posts()) :
      while ( $archquery->have_posts()) :
        $archquery->the_post();
      get_template_part('loop_first', get_post_format());
    endwhile;
endif; ?>

<?php
if($archquery->max_num_pages>1){?>
    <p class="pag">
    <?php
      if ($paged > 1) { ?>
        <a class="pag-alt" href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged -1); //prev link ?>">Ältere Beiträge</a>
                        <?php }
    for($i=1;$i<=$archquery->max_num_pages;$i++){?>
        <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . $i; ?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="selected"':'';?>></a>
        <?php
    }
    if($paged < $archquery->max_num_pages){?>
        <a class="pag-neu" href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged + 1); //next link ?>">Neuere Beiträge</a>
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the code for the category where it is not working

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
        'paged'           => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,
);
  $catquery = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $catquery->have_posts()) :
      while ( $catquery->have_posts()) :
        $catquery->the_post();
      get_template_part('loop_first', get_post_format());
    endwhile;
endif; ?>

<?php
if($catquery->max_num_pages>1){?>
    <p class="pag">
    <?php
      if ($paged > 1) { ?>
        <a class="pag-alt" href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged -1); //prev link ?>">Ältere Beiträge</a>
                        <?php }
    for($i=1;$i<=$catquery->max_num_pages;$i++){?>
        <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . $i; ?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="selected"':'';?>></a>
        <?php
    }
    if($paged < $catquery->max_num_pages){?>
        <a class="pag-neu" href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged + 1); //next link ?>">Neuere Beiträge</a>
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```

The only difference between them is that one is called `$archquery` and the other one `$catquery`

Comment: Do **NOT** use a custom instance of `WP_Query`, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. This will solve the issue. There are really a ton of info on this very subject on-site, so please use the site search

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've used the search before creating this question but haven't found anything that helped me, but since you seem to know some of the questions, would you mind to link me to one of those? Thank you!

Comment: @PieterGoosen even though I haven't found a question about this, your tip with `pre_get_posts` & the `wordpress reference` has helped me enough to solve this problem. If you put your comment as answer, I could mark it as correct.

Comment: I have close voted this as duplicate to the link above as it basically explains everything you need to know about altering the main query plus some extra info you might find helpful ;-)